# Logistic map plot is incorrect (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to iterate and plot the [Logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) nonlinear function given by the equation: `x[n+1] = 4*x[n]*(1-x[n])`.  I have found an implementation of the function here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122101-plotting-f-x-as-a-function-of-x-logistic-map

I have followed the same thing only the number of points `N` and the starting initial condition is different in my implementation. I don't know why I am getting no values in the output; mostly are zero value. When the initial condition is `x[1] = 0.5`, I get the weird plot as given in the picture. But when the initial condition is say 0.3, then I get the proper Logistic map. Theoretically, the initial condition can be any number between 0 and 1. So, why does the code not work when the initial condition is 0.5?

What is the problem?

```
N=20000; % number of data points
x = zeros(1,N);
x(1) = 0.5; % initial condition (can be anything from 0 to 1)


for n = 1:N
    x(n+1) = 4*x(n)*(1-x(n));
end
 plot(x(1:N),x(2:N+1),'rs-')
 xlabel('x_n')
 ylabel('x_{n+1}')
```

Here is the plot

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're getting is correct. Let me explain it with the cobweb diagram below (source: http://sites.saintmarys.edu/%7Esbroad/example-logistic-cobweb.html)

[image: cobweb]

The parabola is the curve `y = 4*x*(1-x)`, the blue linear curve is `y=x`. The way the points `x[n]` are determined is the following:

1. start at point `(x0,y(x0))` (often the line with `(x0,0)` is drawn)
2. go horizontal until you hit the linear curve
3. go vertical  until you hit the parabola. This is your `x[n+1]`.
4. repeat steps 2-3 until infinity or `x[n]=x[n-1]` (stable point) or `x[n]=x[n-m]` (periodicity)

Note the stable points are where the parabola and linear curve intersect.

Applying this method to with your parameters gives:

1. Start in `(0.5,1)`
2. go horizontal to `(1,1)`
3. go vertical to `(1,0)`    (this is `x[1]`)
4. go horizontal to `(0,0)`
5. go vertical to `(0,0)`    (this is `x[2]`)
6. go horizontal to `(0,0)`
7. go vertical to `(0,0)`    (this is `x[3]`)
8. stop

So you just happen to end up the stable point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer with the illustration. If I have understood, I think there is a typo in Point 3) it should be going vertical downward to (1,0) to get x[1] instead of (0,1)? Also, after step 4) which is to the coordinate (0,0), how the next point x[2] is a vertical coordinate (0,0) is unclear. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @RiaGeorge this is indeed a typo, thanks for noticing. After step 4) you are supposed to go vertical until you hit the parabola. However, you are already on the parabola, so it is not needed to go vertical anymore and you can stay where you are.